# Problem with connecting to MS SQL Server with Python AWS Lambda Layer - ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server

Tags: linux, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am in the process of setting up an AWS lambda function to connect to a MS SQL Server database using pyodbc to extract records from a table.

I am receiving an error message

```
('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect))
```

I have built a deployment package on a linux EC2 instance) using the process detailing in the following post:
https://gist.github.com/carlochess/658a98589709f46dbb3d20502e48556b

I have read extensively on this and have changed the path in the odbcinst.ini file to match the directory structure of the lambda layer, but with no luck.

I have also  directory referenced the location of the driver file (libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2).

The error message changes slightly to state that it cannot find the driver efile at the certain location(even though the file does exist)

Comment: Have contacted AWS support regarding this.  It may have something to do with a recent Amazon AMI change for lambda.  Will update when I know more

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pyodbc in a layer, lambda will look for the odbc driver on /opt instead of /var/task. That's probably why you get an error with file not found.

Take a look at the following link on [how to get pyodbc as a lambda layer](https://gist.github.com/diriver63/b72a954fa0da4851d89e5086aa13c6e8)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Diego, I tried to change the path to /opt, but with no success.  I have tried pretty much every combination.  I am on the verge of giving up on getting this working in a Lambda layer and moving onto something else.  I can get the connection to work in in a lambda function when not using a layer!!!

Comment: @CrashOverride How are you doing that with pyODBC as a Deployment Package? I am trying to print the list of drivers and it returns an empty list.

Comment: I am facing some issue on the similar lines. Am able to connect to sql server from a lambda container but not from aws lambda function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62001501/sql-server-connection-works-fine-from-lambda-container-but-fails-after-uploading?noredirect=1#comment109660362_62001501