# SQL server connection works fine from lambda container but fails after uploading zip to aws lambda

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pyodbc

I was following [this](https://medium.com/faun/aws-lambda-microsoft-sql-server-how-to-66c5f9d275ed) medium blog to try to establish a connection to a MSSQL db from a lambda function. I used lambci/lambda:build-python3.8 image to build the container. I followed all the steps mentioned and was able to successfully run the python test script that verifies the connection.

Below is the content of the zip file inside the container.

[image]

However, when I zip it up and upload to lambda, I am receiving below error.

```
START RequestId: 6f3ec44e-aac0-4cc3-b5ed-f8935c4dff4d Version: $LATEST
['bin', 'include', 'lib', 'msodbcsql', 'odbc.ini', 'odbcinst.ini', 'pyodbc.so', 'test.py']
[ERROR] Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/var/task/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    conn=pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=***;PORT=1433;DATABASE=***;UID=***;PWD=***")END RequestId: 6f3ec44e-aac0-4cc3-b5ed-f8935c4dff4d
REPORT RequestId: 6f3ec44e-aac0-4cc3-b5ed-f8935c4dff4d  Duration: 1583.04 ms    Billed Duration: 1600 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 15 MB  
Unknown application error occurred
```

Both the environment are using python -3.8.

test.py

```
import sys
import logging
import pyodbc
import os

logger=logging.getLogger()
arr = os.listdir('/var/task')
print(arr)
conn=pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=***;PORT=1433;DATABASE=***;UID=***;PWD=***")

logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to SQLSever succeeded")
def handler(event,context):
    item_count=0
    crsr=conn.cursor()
    rows=crsr.execute("select @@VERSION").fetchall()
    print(rows)
    logger.info(rows)
    crsr.close()
    conn.close()
```

odbcinst

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/var/task/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2
UsageCount=1
```

Can anyone please help me in debugging this.

### UPDATE

confirming that the file is indeed present
[image]

After putting below in the python code, I see the file is present in lambda.

```
arr = os.listdir('/var/task/msodbcsql/lib64')
print(arr)
```

[image]

Comment: Does your deployment package contains `msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2` as expected?

Comment: @Marcin yes it does.

Comment: It says `file not found`. Maybe its on your local workstation, but when uploaded, lambda reshuffled folders? From your `test.py` on lambda, can you run `os.listdir('/var/task/msodbcsql/lib64')`?

Comment: @Marcin. START RequestId: e1192df5-b492-4cf0-856b-9c78559142f3 Version: $LATEST
['libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2']
[ERROR] Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/var/task/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: I mean, what is the print out of `print(os.listdir('/var/task/msodbcsql/lib64'))`?

Comment: Added the output to the post. It prints this ..['libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2']

Comment: I see. So its definitely there.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev sure. The exception is already there in the post as text. Will keep in mind though.

Comment: I tried to replicate the error by following the tutorial, but I even can't build the package. The tutorial has errors. And its for  python 2.7, but you use 3.8?

Comment: yes. I used 3.8 . And I used aws linux2 ami to launch an ec2 and then installed docker there. So as I told, I am able to make a connection to rds sql server from inside the container using the same drivers. I am not sure why it's not working on aws lamda. The lambda image is supposed to provide an exact environment as aws lambda function!  What errors are you getting ?

Comment: Perhaps not that library but some of its dependencies is not found. Try finding out what specifically is missing with `ldd` as per https://codefarm.me/2016/05/12/linux-commands-for-shared-library-management-and-debugging-problem/.

Comment: Barring that, you can run some minimal reproduction code under `strace` to get the real data on what the system is looking for and where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after days of scratching my head, I was able to resolve this. For anyone who faces similar problem, please follow below steps.

1. try with python - 3.7. It worked for me in 7 and not in 8.
2. Use msodbcsql17 instead of msodbcsql
3. Use unixODBC 2.3.7 [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/unixodbc.html)
4. Change the driver info in odbc, obdcinst config files to `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.`

After doing all of this, I was able to zip it up and successfully deploy in aws lambda.

Hope it helps someone !!

Comment: Did you ever get this working in 3.8? So frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to download layer zip file,
I can confirm that it works only in python3.7 and not in python3.8. You can find detail information and [layer zip file](https://github.com/alexanderluiscampino/lambda-layers) in this [thread](https://gist.github.com/diriver63/b72a954fa0da4851d89e5086aa13c6e8) .

If you'are looking for python3.8 lambda layer, check this [repo](https://github.com/naingaungphyo/lambda_pyodbc_layer-python3.8).